# How to add character to a string several times in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

For example, I need to add 3 spaces to a string 'Hello'. How can I do that using simple SQL? Oracle version is 10g. Thank you.

Comment: give sample data with output.

Comment: @sanjayradadiya let's say I need to add 3 times 'a' to a string 'test' which must result 'aaatest'.

Comment: some equivalent to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using lpad function of oracle

```
select lpad('a',3,'a')||'hello' from dual
```

here **lpad('a',3,'a')** return no of times return current sequence of char

**Edit:**

for add some char before string

```
with temp AS (SELECT 'HELLO' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT lpad(str,length(str)+3,' ') output  FROM temp;
```

Comment: see edited answer also that set any char before current string with no of times.

Comment: sorry, could not mark as solved due to restrictions, now it is done. What does "with no of times" mean? Does it mean edited variant will work faster? Thank you.

Comment: means how many time you want to add char before string i.e i want to add **a** char 3 times before hello then output is **aaahello** that it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean simple concatenation?

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 'HELLO' STR FROM DUAL)
SELECT T.STR || '   '
  FROM T;
```

Comment: not a simple one, but with non-fixed amount of concatenated characters